# No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'L2Loss' with these attrs [[Node: L2Loss = L2Loss[T=DT_INT64](L2Loss/t)]]

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am getting the above-mentioned error while using this tensorflow code:-

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import tensorflow as tf

In [3]: a = tf.constant([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]])

In [4]: norm = tf.nn.l2_loss(a)

In [5]: with tf.Session() as sess:        
   ...:     print(sess.run(norm))
```

Answer (score 3):

You should see something like this

```
InvalidArgumentError: No OpKernel was registered to support Op 'L2Loss' with these attrs.  Registered kernels:
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_FLOAT]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_DOUBLE]
  device='CPU'; T in [DT_HALF]

     [[Node: L2Loss = L2Loss[T=DT_INT32](Const)]]
```

This means that `T` attribute(dtype) is `int32`, but ther are only `float16`, `float32`, `float64` implementations. So you can do this instead

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant([[1,1,1],[2,2,2]], dtype=tf.float32)
norm = tf.nn.l2_loss(a)
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(norm))
```